# Better collapsed loop index computation

Tags: c++, c, performance, optimization

I have the following loop:

```
for (int ij =  begin; ij < ni*nj; ij += step) {
    int j = ij/ni;
    int i = ij - j*ni;
    ...
}
```

what other options are there to compute `i,j` without div/mod?

unfolding the loop is *not* an option.

Comment: Are `ni` and `nj`  completely arbitrary?

Comment: so why collapsed loop? why not nested loop? have you tested it to be slower?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes yes, but they are small, 100 or smaller

Comment: Well, you're performing a division to get j, and then multiplying j by what it was just divided by to compute i; unless you need the side effects of integer division (which can be optimised away in any case), you're doing work you don't need to do here, so you're perfoming a multiplication (not as slow as a division, but still) every iteration.

Comment: @DvirVolk slower and doesn't parallelize well

Comment: @Anycorn what I don't get is this, and correct if I'm making an idiot of myself: if `j = ij/ni` and `i = ij - j*ni` then `i = ij - (ij/ni)*ni` which can be reduced to `i = ij - ij` or `i = 0`. Looks like a bug?

Comment: @Dvir in integer division, `(m/n)*n != (m*n)/n`

Comment: @Anycorn oh right, too much python and you forget the importance of types :)

Comment: I presume you're indexing into some sort of 2D data? If that's the case you might be able to change your representation instead. [height][width] can be changed to [width * height], after which iterating with a stride becomes an traditional 1D loop. Getting element at X / Y instead becomes data[ y * height + x ] which is slightly slower. However the in memory representation of [ width * height ] is usually better and have other advantages.

Comment: Correction to previous, as it would seem I can't edit it. It's data[ y * width + x ].

Comment: Is there a reason not to do this: `for(int k = ni*nj; --k>=0;) a[k] = ...`?

Comment: If unrolling is not an option. that would seem to imply the body of the loop occupies enough time to make the loop overhead irrelevant. I assume you are not among those junior programmers who laser-in on things that don't matter.

Comment: @Ylisar It's rather `x[i], y[j];` - `xy[ij]` blows up memory.

Comment: @Anycorn I'm not quite sure what you're getting at, how does `xy[ij]` blow up memory? If you pack it you'll save a cache line, and with the linear memory approach ( y * height + x ) you'll easily be able to prime the cache in the loop. Often there's a platform specific instrinct for this. If it's as performance sensitive as it seems, then memory layout & vectorizing will give you way more than saving in on div / mods.

Comment: @Ylisar if `i=64, j=64` then `ij=4096`.  This is on GPU card, storing 64x64 elements is expensive.  It's basically cross-product of x and y dimension.

Answer (score 6):

I'd use two variables.  You'll have to use division and modulo on
`begin` and maybe `step` (depending on how big `step` may be), before
entering the loop, but they shouldn't be necessary in the loop.  If 
`step` is less than and a divisor of `ni`, then the following should do
the trick:

```
int end = ni;
int i = begin % ni;
int firstJ = begin / ni;
int j = firstJ;
while ( i < ni ) {
    //  ...
    j += step;
    if ( j >= nj ) {
        ++ i;
        j = firstJ;
    }
}
```

If `step` is not a multiple of `nj - firstJ`, you'll have to do
something about handling the rest when `j >= nj`.

I presume that `i` and `j` are used to index into data.  Depending on
how the data is structured, it might be simpler to either add `begin` to
it up front (if you have a pointer), or to iterate ignoring `begin`,
adding `begin` at each access.  (If you do this, don't forget to correct
`ni` and `nj` accordingly.)

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple variable might be useful

i.e.

```
int end =  ni*nj;
```

and use that in the `for` loop.

Comment: the overhead is by far in integer division

Comment: Just a comment that the computation is carried out each time for the loop. Better just to do it once.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following

```
int k=0, j;
int temp = 1;
int result = 1;
do{
    k++;
    result = ni*k;
}
while(ni*k < ij);
j = result;
```

After this you can calculate i the same way you are doing because for that you are not using div/mod.